# Can i create table or insert data from stored procedure results use CALL in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want use stored procedure results how data to create table or insert. But my example isn't working

```
DECLARE startDate, endDate STRING;
SET startDate = '20200801';
SET endDate = '20200802';

CALL `myproject.dataset.procedure1`(startDate, endDate);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `myproject.dataset.table`
PARTITION BY date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL implies that procedure returns an implicit dataset which could be used in later CREATE TABLE, but this is not how BigQuery store procedure works.

One way is to move the CREATE TABLE to inside the procedure

```sql
DECLARE startDate, endDate STRING;
SET startDate = '20200801';
SET endDate = '20200802';

CREATE PROCEDURE `myproject.dataset.procedure1`(startDate STRING, endDate STRING)
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `myproject.dataset.table`
  AS SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE date >= startDate AND date <= endDate -- just my guess
  PARTITION BY date 
END;
CALL `myproject.dataset.procedure1`(startDate, endDate);
```

If for some reason you don't want CREATE TABLE in procedure body, alternatively, you may use a temp table to bring the resultset out of the procedure, like

```sql
DECLARE startDate, endDate STRING;
SET startDate = '20200801';
SET endDate = '20200802';

CREATE PROCEDURE `myproject.dataset.procedure1`(startDate STRING, endDate STRING)
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE myQueryResults
  AS SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE date >= startDate AND date <= endDate -- just my guess
  PARTITION BY date 
END;
CALL `myproject.dataset.procedure1`(startDate, endDate);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `myproject.dataset.table`
AS SELECT * FROM myQueryResults
PARTITION BY date
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for long response.
The second variant is suiting me, but not completely. 

Because when i use query results in procedure from SELECT, 
if query return "large results"  then procedure crash.

I didn't find how do it in SQL. Documentation says that it can do in api or manually in interface.

My idea is that i don't want have duplicate code. For this i want use procedure (script body) in other procedures.